# How to calculate percentage of variable that meets certain criteria using group_by and summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to calculate the percentage of infarction where `"Yes" == infrc` in veteran and non-veteran groups. I tried something like this:

```
brfss2013 %>% 
  filter(!is.na(veteran3)) %>% 
  group_by(veteran3) %>% 
  summarise("Infarction rate" = sum("Yes" == infrc)/n())
```

To make this work I have to group by the `infrc` parameter too. But in this way `n()` will count in smaller groups, not in the whole veteran and non-veteran groups.

How would I calculate percentage of infarction in veteran and non-veteran groups?

And why does this construction work only if I use `group_by` with the parameter `infrc`?

```
sum("Yes" == infrc)
```

It doesn't make sense because `group_by(infrc)` divides on "Yes", "No" groups by itself.

Comment: We cannot duplicate your problem. Please include a sample data set (can be made up), the output you are getting (if any), and the output that you want to get (can be done manually).

Comment: When I make up a simple dataset your code runs fine without group_by(infrc). But that may be due to version of packages. You might try sum(infrc == "Yes") which will put the vector of values on the left and the singular value on the right. But I don't think this is a problem in tidyverse.

Comment: I just figured out what the problem was. (It was useful to create sample dataset) The infrc parameter contained missing values and this is why sum("Yes" == infrc) returned  NA. When I included infrc parameter in group_by then it created a separate group with missing values, and sum("Yes" == infrc) worked fine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to process separately NA values in a dataset. When construction `sum("Yes" == infrc)` compares "Yes" with NA value it returns NA value for the whole result. This is clear when NA values are averaged but in this case it is a bit confusing. So the solution is to use code like this `sum("Yes" == infrc) & !is.na(infrc)`.